# subtract consecutive rows from a .dat file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

I wish to subtract rows from the preceding rows in a .dat file and then make a new column out of the result. In my file, I wish to do that with the first column time , I want to find time interval for each timestep and then make a new column out of it. I took help from stackoverflow community and wrote a pseudo code in pandas python. but it's not working so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sys import argv
from pylab import *
import csv

script, filename = argv

# read flash.dat to a list of lists
datContent = [i.strip().split() for i in open("./flash.dat").readlines()]

# write it as a new CSV file
with open("./flash.dat", "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(datContent)

columns_to_keep = ['#time']
dataframe = pd.read_csv("./flash.csv", usecols=columns_to_keep)

df = pd.DataFrame({"#time": pd.date_range("24 sept 2016"),periods=5*24,freq="1h")})
df["time"] = df["#time"]  + [pd.Timedelta(minutes=m) for m in np.random.choice(a=range(60), size=df.shape[0])]
df["value"] = np.random.normal(size=df.shape[0])

df["prev_time"] = [np.nan] + df.iloc[:-1]["time"].tolist()
df["time_delta"] = df.time - df.prev_time
df

dataframe.plot(x='#time', y='time_delta', style='r')
print dataframe
show()
```

I am also sharing the file for your convenience, your help is mostly appreciated.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/w4jbxmln9e83355/flash.dat?dl=0

Comment: I think you are looking for `df['time_diff'] = df['#time'].diff()`

Comment: @MaxU, again you the Boss! Thanks a lot